# Approximating Definite Integrals as Sums

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

I have a function $\Omega(x,y)$ that I want to integrate over $[x_1,x_2]$ and $[y_1,y_2]$.
$$I = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\int_{y_1}^{y_2} \Omega(x,y)dydx$$
here $\Omega(x,y)$ is actually Berry curvature (I think its whole expression is not relevant here, if it is, I can edit). The limits are $x: [-2\pi/3,4\pi/3]$, $y: [-2\pi/\sqrt{3},2\pi/\sqrt{3}]$. This integration involves matrices and eigenvalues/vectors of a matrix. I want to evaluate it using the numerical sum approximation. The research paper that I am following claims that the value of the integration (using Gaussian meshes with 2500 points) is $-1$.

I am using the approximation as
$$I = \sum_{x=x_1}^{x_2}\sum_{y=y_1}^{y_2} \frac{\Omega(x,y)}{2\pi}\Delta x\Delta y$$
with $\Delta x = (x_2-x_1)/N$, $\Delta y = (y_2-y_1)/N$ and $N$ is the number of points taken for approximation. I put all this in MATLAB, I get answer $-0.6778$ with $N = 500$. I increased $N=5000$ but still the answer is $-0.6779$.

I wonder what exactly am I doing wrong here? How can I increase the accuracy? Is there any limitation on the approximation that I have used above? Is there any other approximation for numerical integrations?

Note: Using the same code and settings I get the correct result ($-1$) if I use MATLAB's *integral2()* function. which means that there is no bug in my code for $\Omega(x,y)$.

Comment: Does function $\Omega(x, y)$ have any features that complicate numerical integration such as singularities, frequent oscillations or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a better numerical quadrature,like the trapezoidal rule. In general, you would be considering approximations of the form $\int_a^b f(x) dx \approx \sum_{i=1}^N \omega_i f(x_i)$. Assuming that you are using similar integration points on both $x,y$ directions,

$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \int_{y_1}^{y_2} \Omega(x,y) dy dx\approx \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sum_{i,j = 1}^N \omega_i \omega_j \Omega(x_i,y_j)
$$

For the trapezoidal rule, you have that $\omega_1=\omega_N = \frac{h}{2}$ and $\omega_i = h, i=2, \cdots, N-1$. (here $h = \Delta x = \Delta y$)

Comment: it worked. I was not taking the k-points correctly. Thank you very much, your method actually gives good results even with a small $N$ value.